# Unity - How to change what GameObjects are visible with button click events?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am newbie in Unity I am working on `Augmented reality project` where I am showing **3D Objects** based on the marker that is working fine. But what I would like is to show different objects based on click events

Here is the scenario I did so far:

- I created 4 different scenes with 3D objects with markers
- Made one canvas frame where I put 3 buttons on it
- In each button click I am loading next scene, below is the code that I wrote. The problem is it is showing black screen instead of loading new objects. I don't want to load a camera again. Can anyone help me with this?

  ```
  using System.Collections;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using UnityEngine;
  using UnityEngine.SceneManagement; // <<<<<< ADD THIS.

  public class Button_1 : MonoBehaviour
  {

   public void Button_Click()
   {
  Debug.Log("Hello, World!");
  // Application.LoadLevel("Multi Target");
  SceneManager.LoadScene("MultiTarget_1");            // <<<< Then Do this.

      }

       public void Button_Click2()
       {
      Debug.Log("Hello, World!");
  // Application.LoadScene("Multi Target_1");
  SceneManager.LoadScene("NameOfScene");            // <<<< Then Do this.

     }

     public void Button_Click3()
    {
      Debug.Log("Hello, World!");
      Application.LoadLevel("Multi Target_2");

    }

    public void Button_String(string msg)
   {
    Debug.Log("Hello, All!");
    Application.LoadLevel("Multi Target_1");

   }
  }
  ```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pwk8G.jpg)

Comment: Has someone added for you the SecenteManager.LoadScene?

Comment: I have tried that but it is not working can you explain me how can i achieve this ? @IgnacioAlorre

Comment: Just to be sure, what you want to change with the button click is the scene not the objects? Of course each scene has got its own objects, but you try to change the whole scene, isn't?

Comment: I want to change only object on click event not a scene. in one scene i want to change multiple objects using click event.

Comment: But it seems in your script that for each button you try to change the whole scene: SceneManager.LoadScene("NameOfScene");

Comment: Yes i know thats why asking you how can i asking you ? i don't want to change the screen.
current script works fine but it is shows transition in between.

Comment: Ok, so check the answer I gave you below, maybe that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i think you can fix your project by just grouping and hiding the GameObject. its much more simple that you think... i already write a sample code... and i already add a link to do just that on how to group the object if you need help on that... i am an Augmented Reality Developer as well so i understand the problem that you are having.... hope this will help..

URL: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MP62CcK-qTc

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement; // <<<<<< ADD THIS.




public class Button_1 : MonoBehaviour
{
 public GameObject MultiTarget_1, NameOfScene,Multi_Target_2,Multi_Target_1;

 public void Button_Click()
 {
    Debug.Log("Hello, World!");
    HideAll();
      MultiTarget_1.SetActive(true);

    }

     public void Button_Click2()
     {
    Debug.Log("Hello, World!");
    HideAll();
    NameOfScene.SetActive(true);

   }

   public void Button_Click3()
  {
    Debug.Log("Hello, World!");
    HideAll();
    Multi_Target_2.SetActive(true);

  }

  public void Button_String(string msg)
 {
  Debug.Log("Hello, All!");
    HideAll();
    Multi_Target_1.SetActive(true);

 }

 //call this to hide all
 public void HideAll(){
    MultiTarget_1.SetActive(false);
    NameOfScene.SetActive(false);
    Multi_Target_2.SetActive(false);
    Multi_Target_1.SetActive(false);
 }
}
```

Comment: I want to show all the 3 button in bottom of the screens but when i press any button the it is opening new scene where camera is loading again that is the problem of mine i think it is not show hide thing

Comment: I see... what plugin do you use for AR... i use Vuforia https://developer.vuforia.com/home-page i had the same problem with Vuforia to from the pass.  and i had the same problem.  so what i did is just hide/show the object.. on the script that i have create your not loading a new scene.. you just hide and show... i know you what to fix the camera. but the plugin does not work.

Comment: Maybe the developer of that plugin thinks that people will just use one scene for the app.... but ofcourse we don't.. you can try to fix the plugin or you can try to use the script that i created.. or you can try to learn vuforia....

Answer (score 1):

If you have, let's say, two groups of Objects in a Scene, for example:

- GoupA = Cars
- GroupB = Pedestrians

And you want that by default Cars are visible and Pedestrians are not, so as soon as you click a button Cars become invisible in your scene and Pedestrians become visible, one thing you can do is to assign different layers for each group of objects and then change the culling mask of your camera programatically when one of the buttons is pressed.

Step 1:

You need to create two or more layers in your scene, and assign those layers to your GameObjects in your scene, depending on what objects you want to make visible at the same time after button click. You will need to read about this here:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html

Step 2:

Create in your code a reference to the active Camera in your scene:

```
Camera cam;
```

Step 3:

Change your logic inside *Button_Click* methods

```
public void Button_Click1()
{
   // Only render objects in the first layer (Default layer)
        cam.cullingMask = 1 << 0;
}
...
```

These are other things you can do with the culling mask (depending on how you want to display your GameObjects):

```
// Render everything *except* layer 3
camera.cullingMask = ~(1 << 3);

// Switch off layer 3, leave others as-is
camera.cullingMask = ~(1 << 3);

// Switch on layer 3, leave others as-is
camera.cullingMask |= (1 << 3);
```

You can read more about it here:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-cullingMask.html

Comment: thanks for your answer. do you have any sample data for that,
i tried your code but  don't understood the logic behind it.

Comment: we can do one thing by one click we can hide 1st object as well as show 2nd object in same scene.

Comment: Ok I add a few more things. The problem is I am in the office and I don't have time to write all the program, just a brief template of what you may try

Comment: Please check this link that we achieved this things but we are not able to understand what we can do next step see this images when we click on the Ring 2 then it is loading camera again that is my problem

https://ibb.co/nD0hvQ

Comment: Sorry I am in the office, can't really open external links. I need you describe me on here the problems. What I would recommend you is to leave aside for some time the Augmented reality thing, and try what I say in a regular 3D scene. To see if you are able to filter out from you camera the GameObjects after pressing one or another button. (Actually I would even start by making it more simple and intead of buttons in a graphic interface, I would use key from keyword to hide/show different layers). In Unity many things can go wrong, and it is better to go step by step, from simple to complex

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support. please share sample of it when ever you done.

Comment: Yeah, as soon as I am back home I will try those things with my own laptop and share what I get. I would also appreciate if you accept my answer it it was useful for you somehow

Comment: Yeah,sure .I am waiting.

Answer (score 0):

There are **two things.** First check if the correct scene name is given and that it is loading.

If you want to persist the Camera Object over different scenes, then make the object `DontDestroyOnLoad()` using a script attached to the Camera.

Read more here:
 https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html

Comment: Can you please explain what it does ?

Comment: It will help you persist the Camera Object over different scenes.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need different scenes, just 1 scene which has AR sessions and AR session origin.

- create a new blank gameobject and reset its transform ( Scale , rotation , position) so that everything is at 0, except "scale" which will be at 1,
- select all the gameobject you want during "BUTTON 1" click event , make them the child of the new blank gameobject which you created.
- Repeat the same for the all the gameobjects which you want to change during button click.
- After you have created each game object for each button, make them PREFABS. ( just drag the game object from The Hierarchy window to project wind where you can see all your files )
- Create a script and create public or serialised array of Gameobect variable , and save the script.

> public Gameobject obj1[];

- If you are not aware of using arrays, you can just create multiple(number of buttons / Parent Gameobjects you have) gameobject variables
- Drop the script on a gameobject , on the script you will see that you can drag drop the game objects with the same name which you have given during creation of variables.
- In the UI Script ( on button click event) , you just have to enable and disable the prefabs ( VARIABLES WHICH YOU CREATED)  accordingly,